# I am attaching a input statement of html to a variable in php but when i use a div around the input tag the variable does not transfer

Tags: php, html, css

In this code when i use div with a class around the first input tag (which is used to take a number form the user) the value in input does not transfer to the php variable it also does not shows any type of answer.

I am just asking that how i am going to transfer the value of input to the php variable through the div class because without using the div the value is transferred.

```html
<form method="" class="form-horizontal">
        <label class="num1label" for="num1">Enter the first number:</label>
        <div class="aling-center" name="number1">
        <input type="number" class="num2" name="num1" id="num1" placeholder="Enter the First Number"><br>
        </div>
        <label class="num2label" for="num2">Enter the second number:</label>
        <input type="number"class="num2" id="num2" name="num2" placeholder="Enter the Second Number"><br>
        <label for="operator">Choose your operator:</label>
        <select name="operator" id="operator">
            <option>None</option>
            <option>Add</option>
            <option>Subtract</option>
            <option>Multiply</option>
            <option>Division</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit">Calculate</button>
        <p>This is the answer:</p>
    </form>
    </div>
```

```php
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
            $num1=$_GET['number1/num1'];
            $num2=$_GET['num2'];
            $operator=$_GET['operator'];
            switch ($operator) {
                case "None":
                    echo "0";
                    break;
                case "Add":
                    echo $num1+$num2;
                    break;
                case "Subtract":
                    echo $num1-$num2;
                    break;
                case "Multiply":
                    echo $num1*$num2;
                    break;
                case "Division":
                    echo $num1/$num2;
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "0";
                    break;
            }

          }  
    ?>
```

Comment: How is the PHP code being called? Is it part of the same file as the HTML? The method for the form isn't specified either, but in the PHP code, you are looking at the GET variables. Also your _GET for num1 isn't correct, should it simply be `num1` as opposed to `number1/num1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is missing method and you are using GET to fetch the data. Also, you don't have action in your form, so I assume your PHP code is on the same page. Put this in your form.

```
<form method="get" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
```

When fetching data with your PHP code change this line:

```
$num1=$_GET['num1'];
```

Also, put print_r($_GET) so you can see complete set returned by form. Then you will see what goes through and what doesn't so you can make adjustments to the code.

Comment: Nice! Glad to help. Please accept answer so someone else can get help if they need it.